# Iterate a range within a formula in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I haven't been able to find if there's a 'quick' way to iterate the range of a column. In many formulas you have to have to first select the range of the sheet like

```
'Data'!A1:C1
```

I want to know if there's an easy way to iterate the column for the following rows when you drag the formula to the rows below so the formula in the next row is

```
'Data'!B2:C2
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

possible:

```
="Data!"&ADDRESS(ROW(A2), ROW(A2), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(A2), 3, 4)
```

do not forget to convert it into actual range by wrapping it into `INDIRECT`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'Data'!A"&row()&":C"&row()
```

you could change `row()/+-` with a corresponded number for the fit you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).